# MongoDB: sorting by a frequency of one field based on another field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a JSON of objects like this :

```
{
    _id: Object(...),
    address: {...},
    borough: “Brooklyn”, (other values can be: Bronx, Manhattan, Staten Island, Queens)
    cuisine: “American”, (other values can be: Italian, Indian, Chinese, etc)
    grade: “A”,
    score: “9”
{
```

I want to be able to rank each borough by the number of "American" cuisines in that borough, and project the borough and the count of American cuisines in that borough in descending order. I want to be able to do this with `db.collection.aggregate` if possible.

Eg. Sample output:

```
[{borough: "Brooklyn", count: 9312}, {borough: "Bronx", count: 8763}, {borough: "Queens", count: 5461}...]
```

The only way I can come up with is by manually finding the count of American cuisines in each of the five boroughs, and then use that info. But I am hoping to do it in one query. I'm familiar with basic Mongo queries, but I'm really stumped on this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/DAUF2p35BVO

Use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to group by `borough` and count by using [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

and [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to reshape your data

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {  _id: "$borough", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, borough: "$_id", count: 1 } }
])
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it counts the number of ALL cuisines in each borough, as opposed to only "American" cuisines. I also needed to list in descending order, and remove a possibly missing borough field resulting in the value of "Missing." I provided my final solution below

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to @Tushar's answer, except I had to do additional filtering to get rid of missing boroughs, a `$match` to only look at American cuisines, and a `$sort` to rank them in descending order.

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    {$match: {cuisine: "American", borough: {$ne: "Missing"}}}, 
    {$group: {_id: "$borough", count: {$sum: 1}}}, 
    {$sort: {count: -1}}, 
    {$project: {_id: 0, borough: "$_id", count: 1}}
])
```